# LibGDX: Change particle image at runtime?

Tags: libgdx

Is it possible to change the image of the particle effect at runtime?

```
ParticleEffect particleEffect = new ParticleEffect();
particleEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("particle.p"), atlas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Find the `ParticleEmitter` and set a new `Sprite` on it:

```
Sprite someNewSprite = new Sprite( some_texture );
ParticleEmitter emitter = particleEffect.findEmitter("your_emitter_name");
emitter.setSprite(someNewSprite);
```

The new `Sprite` can be any `Sprite`, either constructed from a new file or from a `TextureRegion` in your `atlas`.